# oracle apex export button

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can I add button to interactive report which will export it to excel? So I don't need to press actions button and select there download and select there excel export type

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing you are. However, I don't see an actions button on my report. Where is that button? Do I have to add it? Thanks.

Comment: @DiZou, probably it is hidden. Look at the interactive report settings.

Comment: I found the option to turn it on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I took url that is generated for particular export type. Then I added button and assigned to its click action that url, seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution too:
http://www.apexninjas.com/blog/2012/05/create-a-custom-download-link-for-an-interactive-report/

Just create a submit page button, add a process that redirects you for with the created url.

TLDR:
URL/f?p=< app_id >:< page_id >:< session_id >:< format >

example:

With more than 1 IR in a page:
URL/f?p=< app_id >:< page_id >:< session_id >:IR%5B%5D_< format >

You can get the session_id with `&SESSION.` value.

For example:
f?p=123:45:&SESSION.:IR%5Bexport%5D_CSV --> this goes to the process's URL
and this is the link, where the page jumps (note, you can't get the link from the button, because this is a process and not a link):
f?p=123:45:134898712855:IR%5Bexport%5D_CSV <-- note, that the IR's ID is called 'export'.